# Flipping coins using Scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, optimization, data-structures, iteration

I am trying to solve the Flipping coins problem from codechef in scala. The problem statement is as follows:

> There are N coins kept on the table, numbered from 0 to N - 1.
>   Initally, each coin is kept tails up. You have to perform two types of
>   operations : 1) Flip all coins numbered between A and B. This is
>   represented by the command "0 A B" 2) Answer how many coins numbered
>   between A and B are heads up. This is represented by the command "1 A
>   B". Input : The first line contains two integers, N and Q. Each of the
>   next Q lines are either of the form "0 A B" or "1 A B" as mentioned
>   above.
>
> Output : Output 1 line for each of the queries of the form "1 A B"
>   containing the required answer for the corresponding query.

Sample Input :

```
 4 7
1 0 3
0 1 2
1 0 1
1 0 0
0 0 3
1 0 3 
1 3 3
```

> Sample Output :

```
0
1
0
2
1
```

> Constraints : 1 <= N <= 100000 1 <= Q <= 100000 0 <= A <= B <= N - 1

In the most simplistic way, I was thinking of initializing an Array of Ints in scala as follows:

```
 var coins = new Array[Int](1000)
```

If I encounter the command 0 A B, I will simply set the index of A until B+1 to 1 as follows:

```
 for(i <- 5 until 8){
      coins(i) = 1
    }
```

If I encounter the command 1 A B, I will take a slice of the array from A until B+1 and count the number of 1's in that given slice and I will do it as follows:

```
val headCount = coins.slice(5,8).count(x => x == 1)
```

It seems like this operation take O(n) in the worst case and apparently this can be optimized to be solved in logarithmic time.

Can somebody point out what I might be doing wrong here and how can this problem be solved in the most optimal manner.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of array to store the intervals where the heads can be found. See interval trees wiki article on how you can implement your functions.

Comment: @Elkamina - Thanks. Maybe an implementation of interval trees in scala would work in this particular situation. Need to read up some more on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't know much about scala these days, but i can suggest an answer for the more general question about O(log(n)).  typically such algorithms uses trees, and i think you could do so here.

if you construct a balanced tree, with the coins as leaves, then you could store in each node the total number of coins and the number of heads in the leaves below that node.  you could imagine code that flips coins working out which leaves to visit from the node information, and working in O(n) time (you still need to flip coins).  but if the flipping code also updated the node data then the number of heads would be O(log(n)) because you can use the node info - you don't need to go to the leaves.

so that gives you O(n) for one command and O(log(n)) for the other.

but you can go better than that.  you can make the flip operation O(log(n)) too, i think.  to do this you would add to each node a "flipped" flag.  if set then all the nodes below that point are flipped.  there are some book-keeping details, but the general idea is there.

and if you take this to its logical conclusion, you don't actually need to store the leaves, at least at the start.  you just add nodes with the level of detail required as you process the commands.  at this point you basically have the interval tree mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it seems like I need to work towards an enhanced version of the red-black tree to solve the aforementioned problem in logarithmic time.

Comment: well, you need a balanced tree if you want to avoid problems in the worst case, and a red-black tree is a good implementation of a balanced tree.  a quick search turns up http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/scala/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/RedBlack.scala.shtml if you've not found something similar.

Comment: ps i would suggest not worrying too much about balanced trees first off.  getting the bookkeeping right for an unbalanced tree will be much easier (certainly easier to debug).  once you have that working, then make it balanced (the process of rebalancing is going to require you juggle around the flags and counts - it's going to be tricky, and easier if you already know that the unbalanced code works).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed algorithmic breakdown and the example. I will mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One clean way to model this is as a [`BitSet`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/BitSet.html), where the integer values in the set represent the indices of the heads on the board. Then you can flip the coins in a range like this:

```
def flip(coins: BitSet, a: Int, b: Int) = coins ^ BitSet(a to b: _*)
```

You can count the heads in a range similarly:

```
def heads(coins: BitSet, a: Int, b: Int) = (coins & BitSet(a to b: _*)).size
```

Or the (probably faster) mutable `java.util.BitSet` versions:

```
import java.util.BitSet

def flip(coins: BitSet, a: Int, b: Int) { coins.flip(a, b + 1) }
def heads(coins: BitSet, a: Int, b: Int) = coins.get(a, b + 1).cardinality
```

This isn't necessarily optimal, but it's a fairly efficient approach, since you're just flipping bits.

Comment: Thanks. What does the statement BitSet(a to b: _*) do?